# Receive data via HTTP in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, http

I have already posted this question on the MATLAB forum, but am still hoping in a solution/reply.

I need to access CSV-formatted data on a server, which requires a token for me to be granted access. My colleagues usually access this service with Python. However, as my code is all in MATLAB, I would prefer the data in MATLAB so that I can use my existing functions, which I have already verified.
In Python, we use the requests package as follows:

```py
timeseries_url = 'https:// .... /csv'
payload = { 'variable': ['var1','var2'], 'platform_serial' : 'name_of_platform' , 'from' : 'start_time' , 'to' : 'end_time' }
header = {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + 'authorisation_token'}
# Get the response:
response = requests.get(timeseries_url, headers=header, params=payload)
df = pandas.read_csv(io.StringIO(response.text))
```

I have been reading the MATLAB documentation for the HTTP interface. However, I have noticed there is no equivalent get command, but only the send.
I think the token should be entered in the `matlab.net.http.HTTPOptions` object as `'Credentials'`. Similarly, the header could be the `'Header'` `matlab.net.http.RequestMessage`. Besides, I think the payload could be obtained through `'getFields'`. Are these assumptions correct?

How can I best achieve this task in MATLAB? Additionally, how can I change the data from CSV to matrices/cells for later use? I do not think using `csvread` or `readmatrix` here is appropriate.

My alternative is the MATLAB engine for Python, but I would prefer a neat, all-MATLAB solution.

Comment: Have you tried using [webread](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/webread.html) with [weboptions](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/weboptions.html?s_tid=doc_ta) ?

Comment: No, thanks for the tip. I will now have a look at that

Comment: Ok, it looks like webread is what I need. However, my main problem now is the Python dictionary. It is clear that the website has specific fields 'variable' , 'platform_serial', 'from','to' and 'Authorisation'. How can I get this in MATLAB? With a Map Container? But then how will it work with the webread query?

Comment: The server expects a JSON payload right? Create a struct in MATLAB and use [jsonencode](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/jsonencode.html) to get your payload

Comment: Exactly. Thanks! I'll try and let you know how it goes.

Comment: Sure thing, let me know if you have any issues. I'll have some time later to write up an answer.

Comment: I feel like I am almost there. The json conversion works like magic. However, I still have problems specifying the header (i.e. the token I need to get access - unique identifier) and the payload. Is it through weboptions? I have tried 'HeaderField' and 'ContentReader' unsuccessfully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation of the Python requests module, it looks like the payload is actually only used to [encode the URL](https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#passing-parameters-in-urls).

Here's an example code for MATLAB which you should be able to adapt to your data to submit a successful request:

```
% URL and token data.
timeseries_url = 'https:// .... /csv';
auth_token = '';

% Structure for the payload.
struct_payload.key1 = 'value1'
struct_payload.key2 = 'value2'

% Find names of fields in struct_payload.
field_names = fieldnames(struct_payload);

% Format url for query.
encoded_url = [timeseries_url '?'];

for i = 1:numel(field_names)
    encoded_url = [encoded_url field_names{i} '=' struct_payload.(field_names{i}) '&'];
end
encoded_url(end) = [];

% Create weboptions object with headers.
options = weboptions('HeaderFields',{'Authorization' ['Bearer ' auth_token]});

% Submit webread request.
data = webread(encoded_url, options);
```

Comment: Great, it worked great, thanks! The only inaccuracy is that an extra space is required in 'Bearer ', but other than that it works great.

Comment: @EnricoAnderlini Awesome, happy to help. I added the extra space :)